# Base and derived classes in Boost.Python

Tags: python, c++, inheritance, boost

I have two classes - lets say A and B. The class B is the child class of A and both have the function H, such that:

```
class A{
  public:
  A(){;;}  // ctor
  virtual ~A(){ ;; } // destr.
  virtual double H(int i,int j){ 
    std::cout<<"Calling the base function H. Level is too abstract\n";
    exit(0);
    return 0.0;
  }// H
};// class A
```

The derived class B is:

```
class B : public A{
  public:
  B(){;;}  // ctor
  ~B(){ ;; } // destr.
  double H(int i,int j){ 
    return 1.0;
  }// H
};// class B
```

I also have the function that takes arguments of the class A type:

```
double f(A x){
  return x.H(1,1); 
}
```

I want to use object of the derived type B as an argument to this function in Python. So, I export the two classes and the function as explained [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/boost.python/Inheritance):

```
BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(modAB){
  class_<A>("A", no_init);

  class_<B, bases<A> >("B", init<>())
    .def("H", &B::H)
  ;    

  def("f", &f);
}
```

So in Python I do:

```
>>> from modAB import *
>>> x = B()
>>> res = f(x)
```

As the output I see that the method H was called from the base class, not from the derived class as I expected:

```
Calling the base function H. Level is too abstract
```

So, my question is where I'm wrong and what do I possibly miss?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`double f(A x)` passes `x` by value so passing an object of type `B` will slice off its derived virtual functions.

To fix it you need to pass `const A&`:

```
double f(const A& x)
```

Comment: Peter, thank you - i had the feeling that it could cause the problem. Ideally, I would like the Python-exposed function with the signature like f(A& x), but i'm not sure if this can be done - because the Python "objects" are already references. Do you know if that is possible to expose f(A& x) function to Python somehow? What would be the other way around?

Comment: just want to confirm - the method works! many thanks to Peter. This actually extends my look on the possible ways of exposing functions and classes to Python - for some reason i was convinced that one can't use references in the Python-exposed function.

Comment: @user938720 The Python object _holds_ the C++ object, and Boost.Python just _extracts_ a handle to the held object when invoking the C++ function.  While not used here, in general, custom converters are one of the few areas where lvalue references are explicitly not supported.